# How can I move my content below some floated divs?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have been trying to make a web site so I can test some things, in this I was trying to put the `<div>`s of the container on top of the page and the rest of the content should be on the bottom of that div.

But the result that I get is the 3 `<div>`s with the `class="square"` on the left of the page and the rest of the content on the left of the container div.

So my question is, how can I correct the page layout?

And another question that I have is how does the `float` work?

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">Quadrado 1</div>
  <div class="square">Quadrado 2</div>
  <div class="square">Quadrado 3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>this paragraph should be under the div with the "container" class</p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
  <h2>Sed a porttitor nisl. Praesent a nisl nec nisi interdum efficitur a nec metus.</h2>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
  <h2>Sed a porttitor nisl. Praesent a nisl nec nisi interdum efficitur a nec metus.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to the `p` element to prevent floating elements on both sides of it.

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">Quadrado 1</div>
  <div class="square">Quadrado 2</div>
  <div class="square">Quadrado 3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <p style="clear: both;">this paragraph should be under the div with the "container" class</p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
  <h2>Sed a porttitor nisl. Praesent a nisl nec nisi interdum efficitur a nec metus.</h2>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
  <h2>Sed a porttitor nisl. Praesent a nisl nec nisi interdum efficitur a nec metus.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `flex`, why not use it for `.square` as well? Get rid of `float` at all.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}    

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="square">Quadrado 1</div>
  <div class="square">Quadrado 2</div>
  <div class="square">Quadrado 3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>this paragraph should be under the div with the "container" class</p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
  <h2>Sed a porttitor nisl. Praesent a nisl nec nisi interdum efficitur a nec metus.</h2>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </h1>
  <h2>Sed a porttitor nisl. Praesent a nisl nec nisi interdum efficitur a nec metus.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @John but if I do that all of the `<div>`s that I have will display one  below another. I wanted to make then on the left of each other, that's why I used `float`. But for the purpose of my question, your answer worked

Comment: @AlexandrePreto No they won't. Run the code snippet.